# JSON error if there is space in value or null

Tags: json

I have three variables which I want to transfer them to another function on changing a dropdown value as below:

```
$.each(data, function () {
  var jName = this.job_name;
  var jInv = this.job_inv;
  var jDwg = this.job_dwg;

  var jobVal = {
    "job_name": jName,
    "job_inv": jInv,
    "job_dwg": jDwg
  };

  jobVal = JSON.stringify(jobVal);
  $('#job').append('<option value=' + jobVal + '>' + this.job_inv + " " + this.job_name + this.job_dwg + '</option>');

});
```

and second function:

```
$('#job').change(function () {
  $('#itemList').empty();

  var jobVal = JSON.parse($('#job').val());
  var jName = jobVal.job_name;
  var jInv = jobVal.job_inv;
  var jDwg = jobVal.job_dwg;
  $('#txt1').val(jName);

  $.getJSON('/Demo/getItem', {
    job_name: jName,
    job_inv: jInv,
    job_dwg: jDwg
  }, function (data) {

    var count = 0;
    $.each(data, function () {
      count += 1;
      $('#itemList').append('<tr><td>' + count + '</td><td>' + this.item +
        '</td><td>' + this.description + '</td ><td >' +
        this.quantity + '</td ><td >' + this.unitPrice +
        '</td ><td > ' + this.itemPrice + '</td ></tr>');
    });
  }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error getting Items!');
  });
});
```

Everything works well until one of the variables contains a space or null value. Any solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you *want* to happen when one of the values contains a space or is null? Do you simply want to *exclude* these values?

Comment: I want to transfer the data to my controller as it is

Comment: Can you post your Controller here?

Answer (score 0):

You must check your json value at data entry time by below code

`jobVal = JSON.stringify(jobVal);
  $('#job').append('<option value=' + jobVal.replace("", "_") + '>' + this.job_inv.replace("", "_") + " " + this.job_name.replace("", "_") + this.job_dwg.replace("", "_") + '</option>');`

A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
the following three literal names:

false null true

Comment: Is there any way to transfer data as it is instead of changing the format? Since "_" or any other character might be part of real data.